# Would crontab work like this?

Tags: php, linux, curl, debian, cron

I have here some php scripts that must run every 5 Minutes everyday.
So I put this to crontab:

---

```
*/5 * * * * php curl ht*p://url.url/del/crawl_data.php >/dev/null 2>&1

*/5 * * * * php curl ht*p://url.url/del/delete_channel.php >/dev/null 2>&1

*/5 * * * * php curl ht*p://url.url/rules.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

---

Would this work? 
I'm now waiting but nothing happens at all, why?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Remove the ` >/dev/null 2>&1` parts and take a look at the messages (the user should receive a local mail with the output). If you need more help after, please add the messages to your question.

Comment: I'm getting this error:   http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JfCJZra2

Comment: yea but which extension? I must exactly change now what on php_cli?

Comment: I changed now from php to curl only, is this ok or would I to stay at php and curl?

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have to check if "php" on the crontab mean a user named php or the php bin. than edit "ht*p" to become "http". and i advise to keep the output of the execution in file under /tmp directory. also you have to check the log of crontab to check if scripts are executed or not .

Try this now :

```
*/5 * * * * root curl "http://url.url/del/crawl_data.php" >> /tmp/myLogFile

*/5 * * * * root curl "http://url.url/del/delete_channel.php" >> /tmp/myLogFile

*/5 * * * * root curl "http://url.url/rules.php" >> /tmp/myLogFile
```